# How do you overwrite items in a list?

Tags: python-3.x

How do you overwrite items in a list?

I tried this, but it didn't work.

```
numbs = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
i = 0
for numb in numbs:
    numbs[i] = (numb+5)
    i+=i+1
```

Comment: What do you mean it "didn't work"? What was your error and your expected ouptput?

Comment: IndexError: list assignment index out of range on line 4

Comment: typo `i+=1` ?...

Comment: Expected output: numbs [10, 15, 20, 25, 30]

Comment: Using a for-each loop and manually incrementing a variable is an anti-pattern. Consider removing your declaration and incrementing of `i` and change your for loop to `for i in range(len(numbs))`.

Comment: Great I was looking at the wrong line, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
numbs = [numb+5 for numb in numbs]
```

Comment: OP wants to modify `numbs` itself, so this should be `numbs = [numb+5 for numb in numbs]`

Comment: this is very simple and one liner solution

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
numbs = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
i = 0
for numb in numbs:
    numbs[i] += 5
    i += 1
print(numbs)
```

The output i got from it was: [10, 15, 20, 25, 30]